# How to reset password for HP Proliant ML330 G6

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, password-reset

We have HP Proliant ML330 G6 and its BIOS is closed with password. Password is already forgotten and we can't get there. Is there any way to crack or reset a password at this box?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't password-protect your BIOS... Maintenance nightmare.

To remedy this, you will need physical access to the server... You're going to be looking for a set of DIP switches on the motherboard:

[image]

- Remove the server cover.
- Locate the System Maintenance Switch, position 6, and move the switch to the "On=Clear NVRAM" position.
- Power the server back on until Power-On Self-Test begins.
- After POST has started, power-cycle the server off.
- Move the System Maintenance Switch back to the "Off" position.

Comment: Thank you! Absolutely agree with you. It was not me, who set the password.

Answer (score 5):

There's a set of switches on the motherboard, one of them is Password Override (ie Take any password, not just the right one)

System Maintenance SW1 - iLO Security (Password)
System Maintenance SW5 - BIOS Password Required

Note: The switches are present on almost every modern HP Server, and usually the same layout.